# How to keep track of call status agora.io

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, agora.io

I'm working on a video calling app where a user can talk to a sales rep.

I have 2 edge cases that I don't know how to solve.

Since user 1 opens a channel and waits for the other person to enter the call.

What happens if:

> -Person 2 never enters the call, and person 1 leaves the app?

> -Both people are in the call: Both people leave the app?

Since I can't prevent users from switching apps, how could I keep track of this cases so that I can close the channel so it doesn't continue generating cost?

I've seen cases where I test the video calls, leave the app, and then I see 4 hour calls registered on my agora console.